# How do I prevent pouch items from auto-refilling?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

When I add a consumable item to a character’s pouch, it is set to last for a limited amount of time. When the timer runs out, the pouch is automatically refilled.

This means if I have ten steaks in my inventory, then add one steak to my pouch, the pouch will keep refilling until all ten steaks have been used up.

Is there a way to prevent pouch items from automatically refilling?

Comment: I never found a way, I won't post an answer though as I'm not sure that there isn't one, just I never found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to swap the item with something of a lower duration or less utility or sell the items that aren't used. It seems there is no way to remove or cease using a food after the current one.

Answer (score 0):

[As Seiyria mentioned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/327336/181240), there is no direct way to prevent a pouch item from refilling. There are a few ways to mitigate this:

- Replace the pouch item with something cheaper. (Wait until the item timer gets close to 0 if you want to maximize usage)
- Only buy one of a pouch item so it cannot refill
- Sell excess pouch items
- Use the same pouch item across multiple characters