# Do pouch refills count for favorite item conditions on the Affinity Chart?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

Some Affinity Chart unlocks for certain blades have a condition to use a blade's favorite pouch items a certain number of times. Some unlock conditions require using a specific item (Pyra) while others allow any item in a specific category (Dromarch).

If a blade's favorite pouch item is [auto-refilled](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/327306/how-do-i-prevent-pouch-items-from-auto-refilling), does it count towards the item usage conditions for Affinity Chart unlocks?

[image: Dromarch's affinity chart condition for favorite pouch items]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. After testing with Dromarch and Roc, I can confirm that pouch refills count towards Affinity Chart conditions for using items.